# How to append single quotes in string Swift?

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I have a string like `20230914T07:37:43.000Z`. I want to append single quotes and hyphens, and my result should be like this: `2023-09-14'T'07:37:43.000Z`.

I have tried the code below, but a backslash is automatically added to my string, resulting in `2023-09-14'T'07:37:43.000Z`.

Code:

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = formatter

var welcome = "20230914T07:37:43.000Z"
welcome.insert("-", at: welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
welcome.insert("-", at: welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
print(2023-09-14T07:37:43.000Z)

// Option 1
welcome.insert(#"'"#, at: welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 10))
welcome.insert(#"'"#, at: welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 12))

// Option 2
welcome.insert("'", at: welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 10))
welcome.insert("'", at: welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 12))

dateString = welcome

let date: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: dateString)
print(date) // -> nil
return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date!); ////Crash

// Output: '2023-09-14'T'07:37:43.000Z'
```

I have tried both options, but I still get a backslash automatically added to my string.

Question: How to append single quotes and hyphens without black slash?

Can someone please explain to me how to do this, I've tried with the above code but have no results yet. Please Correct me if I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are trying to do it for visual reasons, here is a nice trick, try using ` instead of ', and its hard for  the users to know the difference, and you don't have to fight with MySQL or other systems that crap out on lack of ' termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to add apostrophes to the `welcome` string. The apostrophes are only needed around the `T` in the `dateFormat` of the date formatter to indicate that the `T` is to be treated literally and not as a format specifier.

You should also avoid adding the hyphens to the `welcome` string and simply remove the hyphens from the `dateFormat`. The whole idea of a `dateFormat` is to choose a date format that matches the strings you will be parsing.

With all of that in mind, your code simply becomes:

```swift
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

var welcome = "20230914T07:37:43.000Z"

if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: welcome) {
    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = formatter

    return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
} else {
    // return some indicator of failure
}
```

---

Or you may wish to use [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) to work with strings in one of the supported ISO8601 formats.

Comment: Not related to the question itself but this would still have some issues if it goes to production. You are not setting the date formatter's calendar and locale before setting the dateFormat. Try this code with your device's calendar set to Buddhist calendar or simply change your device's 24h setting to 12h and try to parse a date string with time hour after 12pm.

Comment: @LeoDabus Good points. I was focusing more on the specifics of the question but setting the locale to `en_US_POSIX` and the calendar to Gregorian would be a good idea. Then again, using `ISO8601DateFormatter` as I suggest at the end would be even simpler.